# My terminal's PS1 is 2 lines, when I clear the screen, the first line gets cleared as well, how can I prevent this?

Tags: terminal, zsh, ps1

Using zsh / oh-my-zsh / `amit` theme. Mac / iTerm.

`$PS1` is

```
$(_user_host)${_current_dir} $(git_prompt_info) $(_ruby_version)
%{$fg[$CARETCOLOR]%}▶%{$resetcolor%}
```

When I clear my screen (with `cmd+k`), it clears the first line, leaving just the `▶` as my prompt. Is there a way to prevent it from clearing the first line?

(I know this is super petty, it's just annoying the heck outta me).

Comment: I removed the bash tag.

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, probably, but use Control-L instead of Command-K.

Comment: The difference being, of course, that Command-K is handled by the terminal, if even the current command running *in* the terminal isn't currently accepting input, whereas Control-L is read by and acted up by the shell.